# Editing div content from a different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to edit a div's class name that is on my homepage based on a toggle switch but the toggle switch is on a different page. This script worked when the div was on the same page but now its not functioning.

```
function changeStatus(obj,temp) {
var toggleid = $(obj).attr('name');
var toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("statusinput")[toggleid];
var statusEffect = $.get('index.html', null, function(text){
                         alert($(text).find('#name'));
                         });
if(toggle.checked){
    statusEffect.innerHTML = "Arrived";
    statusEffect.classList.remove("statusp");
    statusEffect.classList.add("statusa");
}else{
    statusEffect.innerHTML = "Pending";
    statusEffect.classList.remove("statusa");
    statusEffect.classList.add("statusp");
}
```

every time I run this I get a error [Object object]. This is supposed to make it so when the user checks the box the div switches from "Pending" to "Arrived"

Answer (score 1):

You can only amend the DOM of the page which is currently loaded. If you want to change a different page based on an action in a another one you'd need to persist the state of the user's interactions and then amend the other page when it loads. To do that you can use localStorage, sessionStorage, session, cookies, or AJAX to store information on the server

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of JQuery:

```
var statusEffect = $.get('index.html', null, function(text){
                         alert($(text).find('#name'));
                         });
```

$.get() will return a promise, not a DOM element. [Link to docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Further down, you are trying to use it like a DOM element.

```
if(toggle.checked){
    statusEffect.innerHTML = "Arrived";
    statusEffect.classList.remove("statusp");
    statusEffect.classList.add("statusa");
}else{
    statusEffect.innerHTML = "Pending";
    statusEffect.classList.remove("statusa");
    statusEffect.classList.add("statusp");
}
```

If you wish to alter the class name of a div on another page you would have to store that information somewhere, such as a cookie. When that page loads check the cookie to give the div the correct class name.